# PyQt слайдер из кнопок

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pyqt, pyside2

Нужно на PyQt реализовать слайдер из кнопок. Кнопки будут добавляться динамически, в зависимости от действий пользователя.

Изображение слайдера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать обычный слайдер я знаю. Но как реализовать подобный я даже представления не имею. Даже не пойму с чего начать.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, как у вас реализован обычный слайдер и чем этот обычный слайдер отличается от того что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Обычный слайдер не реализован. Мне он не нужен.
Короче, решил как реализовать: Это просто будет таблица с одной строчкой, где будут добавляться колонки с кнопками. Колонки со стрелками будут постоянно  первые и последние. Ну короче затея ясна. Если есть более изящное решение, буду рад узнать.